# Mutation Observer callback does not fire

Tags: mutation-observers

[image: Screenshot of fields in validation-error state]

I cannot get my MutationObserver callback to fire when validation error messages are added to my form. Per the screenshot, if the `firstname` input is left empty, when you click submit, the classes 'required-entry' and 'mage-error' are added, as well as 'aria-describedby' (all by JS using the platform's validation scripts). So I figure this code should put something in the console.

```
const targetNode = document.getElementById('firstname');

const observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutationList, observer) {
    if (mutation.type === "childList") {
        console.log("A child node has been added or removed.");
    } else if (mutation.type === "attributes") {
        console.log(`The ${mutation.attributeName} attribute was modified.`);
    }
});

observer.observe(targetNode, { attributes: true, childList: true, subtree: true });
```

I've made this as simple as possible for the demo. Initially I wanted to detect the appearance of '#firstname-error', grab its text and put it somewhere else, but couldn't get it working.

Comment: DOM doesn't change when `input` element's value property (not attribute) is changed so MutationObserver won't help. Add an event listener for `input` event instead.

Comment: My simplified example maybe didn't help - it didn't work either when the `targetNode` was a container div (like 'field-name-firstname') and I wanted to observe the creation of div#firstname-error, which appears only if there is a validation error. I can't get it to observe / react to anything added by the validation script.